# How should I work with CLOB or NCLOB datatype in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, clob, nclob

I read these datatypes are for storing long String, so I decided to use NCLOB for storing comments and Bio.I just wanted to try, I created a table :

```
create table cmd(content NCLOB);
```

and tried to insert a long string in the table but just three line is inserted.
something like this picture :
[image]

Did I use NCLOB in wrong way?What is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data has been inserted correctly, before selecting from your table in sqlplus use the following:

```
set long 9000
select * from cmd;
```

Here is a link to the documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG088

Cheers